# Is there a way to refer to the end of a vector?

Tags: r, vector

I don't want to save the huge intermediate results for some of my calculations, and hence want to run some tests without saving these memory expensive vectors.

Say, during the computation I have a vector of arbitrary length l.

But I don't know what l is, and I can't save the vector in the memory.

Is there a way I can refer the length of the vector, something like

```
vec[100:END] or vec[100:-1] or vec[100:last]
```

Please note that `vec` here is not a variable, and it only refers to an intermediate expression which will output a vector.

I know length, head and tail functions, and that vec[-(1:99)] is an equivalent expression.

But, I actually want to know if there is some reference that will run an iteration from a specified number to the 'end' of the vector.

Thanks!!

Comment: Cannot quite figure out why this is not the answer: `vec[100:length(vec)]`

Comment: This is an answer, but not the desired one. "I actually want to know if there is some reference that will run an iteration from a specified number to the 'end' of the vector." I dont want to compute `length(vec)`.

Comment: @Shambho: then the answer is "no".

Comment: Why get angry on this? Is this not a valid question?

Comment: @Reed: My question was for those who are down voting the question without any justification.

Comment: When dealing with vectors, the answer to your literal question is "no," but that doesn't mean there isn't another way to handle it. Perhaps the way you are envisioning the creation of this data needs to be revisited, where "vector" is not the ideal mechanism. For instance, perhaps you need to write a function that calculates each datum and allows you (the caller) to specify the starting point (defaulting to 1, for example).

Comment: Why exactly can't you save the vector in memory? How is it being created and what are you trying to do with it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm probably not understanding your question. If this isn't useful let me know and I'll delete it.

I gather you want to extract the elements from a vector of arbitrary length, from element N to the end, without explicitly storing the vector (which is required if you want to use, e.g. `length(vec)`). Here are two ways:

```
N <- 5    # grab element 5 to the end.
set.seed(12)
(1:sample(N:100,1))[-(1:(N-1))]
# [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11

set.seed(12)
tail(1:sample(N:100,1),-(N-1))
# [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

Both of these create (temporarily) a sequence of integers of random length (>=5), and extract the elements from 5 to the end without self-referencing.

Comment: Pop `rev(x)[1]` up there, just for fun.

Comment: @RichardScriven That get's the value of the last element, no? I think OP wants a vector containing elements from a given index to the last element??

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned memory a could of times.  If you're concerned about memory and assigning large objects, you should take a look at the `Memory-limits` documentation, and the related links.  First, there are ways to operate on the language in R.  Here I only assign one object, the function `f`, and use it without making any other assignments.

```
> f <- function(x, y) x:y   ## actually, g <- ":" is only 96 bytes
> object.size(f)
# 1560 bytes
> f(5, 20)[3:7]
# [1]  7  8  9 10 11
> object.size(f)
# 1560 bytes
> f(5, 20)[3:length(f(5, 20))]
# [1]  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
> object.size(f)
# 1560 bytes
```

You can also use an `expression` to hold an unevaluated function call.

```
> e <- expression(f(5, 20))  ## but again, g <- ":" is better
> eval(e)
# [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
> eval(e)[6:9]
# [1] 10 11 12 13
> eval(e)[6:length(eval(e))]
# [1] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
> rev(eval(e))
# [1] 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5
```

Depending of the type of data you're working with, there are ways to 
avoid using large amounts of memory during a session.  Here are a few related to 
your question.

```
memory.profile()
gc()
#          used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
# Ncells 274711 14.7     531268 28.4   531268 28.4
# Vcells 502886  3.9    1031040  7.9   881084  6.8
```

?gc() is good knowledge to have, and I can't really explain it.  Best to read 
about it. Also, I just learned about memCompress() and memDecompress() for 
in-memory compression/storage.  Here's a look  Also, if you're working with 
integer values, notifying R about it can help save memory.
That's what the `L` is for on the end of the `rep.int()` call.

```
x <- rep.int(5L, 1e4L)
y <- as.raw(x)
z1 <- memCompress(y)
z2 <- memCompress(y, "b")
z3 <- memCompress(y, "x")

mapply(function(a) object.size(get(a)), c('x','y','z1','z2','z3'))
#     x     y    z1    z2    z3 
# 40040 10040    88    88   168
```

And there is also

```
delayedAssign("p", rep.int(5L, 1e5L))
```

which is a `promise object` that takes up 0 bytes of memory until it is first evaluated.